# how can I generate a normal distribution with a skew in javascript?

Tags: javascript, random, statistics, d3.js, normal-distribution

I need to generate a normal distribution with a skew that fits the following constraints

1. negativeSigma (minus one standard deviation)
2. mean (value the distribution is centered upon)
3. positiveSigma (plus one standard deviation)

The intent is to have a distribution function that will generate random values.

I've tried using Math.random() and also tried the normal and irwinHall distribution from d3.js but unable to figure it out. Are there any JS libraries that might help? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: I think the problem you are experiencing is that you are using the wrong terminology. What you've shown is not a normal distribution. Once you've discovered the correct terminology (perhaps by asking a question on the [Math StackExchange](http://math.stackexchange.com/)), then you will be closer to a result.

Comment: There are quite a few javascript stat library out there. http://www.jstat.org/ offers you a normal distribution out of the box. See http://www.jstat.org/demonstration